# I can't auto-include a piece of code on all post pages on Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to auto-include a piece of code on all post pages on **Jekyll**.

For example, after the first `<p></p>` i want to `{% include adsense.html %}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [post excerpt](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts)

In `_config.yml` set `excerpt_separator: <!--more-->`

In a post you now have :

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date:   2015-03-07 18:19:51
---
page excerpt
<!--more-->
page content
[...]
```

And in your `_layouts/post.html` :

```
[...]
{{ page.excerpt }}
{% include adsense.html %}
{{ page.content }}
[...]
```